# Синонимизировать и объединить [express.js] и [express]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Нужно синонимизировать и объединить [express.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express.js) (311 вопросов) и [express](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express) (131 вопрос).

По [express.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express.js) намного больше вопросов. Предлагаю её сделать основной. Голосуем за ответы.

P.S. на SOen основная [express](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основной сделать [express](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express).

Comment: Этот вариант используется в заголовках на сайте фрэймворка https://expressjs.com/. Даже пакет в npm называется так же.

Comment: @mymedia это да, но у нас вроде практика обычно основывается на количестве вопросов по метке, чтоб людям проще было искать )

Answer (score 0):

Основной сделать [express.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express.js).